# Issuing Certificate For Child Domain After Issuing One From Parent From Same CA

Tags: certificate, windows-server-2019, ad-certificate-services

I am trying it issue a certificate as part of my Enrollment ability for a 2FA device for our child domain from our parent domain. I was able to do this months ago but now it won't let me do the child domain credentials issue.

Process works as follows. I make a 2FA device for a user on my parent domain and do Enroll ON Behalf in the certificate console as I have enrollment permission.

1. I select the Active Directory Policy
2. I select my Enrollment Agent Certificate which is valid.
3. I select our 2FA template to issue it.
4. I select the Parent domain user name and issue that certificate without a problem.

Then I do the same for the child domain account.

1. I select the Active Directory Policy
2. I select my Enrollment Agent Certificate which is valid.
3. I select our 2FA template to issue it.
4. I select the Parent domain user name and attempt to issue the certificate and I get the following error:

   Configuration Information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied
   SERVER.DOMAIN.NET\SERVER-CA
   Denied by Policy Module
   Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied. 0x80070547 (WIN32: 1351 ERROR_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO)
   The Request ID is 1200

This doesn't make any sense. DCDIAG shows everything is fine. I can remote to the server without a problem. I just issue the certificate for the parent domain account from the same CA. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**: This continues to be an issue. After almost 30 minutes It would accept the certificate but why does it cause this issue? It is almost like it needs to replicate domain information across all the DCs. Is there a way to fix this issue or a permission I can set on the child domain to speed this up?